# Duplicar o resultado do Select Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

Tenho um registro que é um recibo, e no select, quero que a linha venha duplicada. Ex:

```
Select * from recibos where codigo =1;
```

Resultado:

```
codigo|cliente|valor|emitente|data
  1    Fulano   10    Ciclano  19/10/2017
```

Resultado que preciso:

```
codigo|cliente|valor|emitente | data       |  via
  1    Fulano   10    Ciclano   19/10/2017     1
  1    Fulano   10    Ciclano   19/10/2017     2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumindo que:

```
CREATE TABLE tb_recibos (
    codigo integer,
    cliente text,
    valor integer,
    emitente text,
    data date
);

INSERT INTO tb_recibos ( codigo, cliente, valor, emitente, data )
VALUES ( 1, 'Fulano', 10, 'Ciclano', '2017.10.19' );
```

**Solução #1** *(Menos compacta, plano complexo )*:

```
SELECT
    r.codigo,
    r.cliente,
    r.valor,
    r.emitente,
    r.data,
    s AS via
FROM
    tb_recibos AS r 
CROSS JOIN
    generate_series( 1, 2 ) AS s
WHERE
    codigo = 1;
```

**Solução #2** *(Mais compacta, plano simples)*:

```
SELECT
    r.codigo,
    r.cliente,
    r.valor,
    r.emitente,
    r.data,
    generate_series( 1, 2 ) as via
FROM
    tb_recibos AS r 
WHERE
    codigo = 1;
```

Veja funcionando no [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/f1906/2/1)

Comment: Obrigado Lacobus, engraçado que no fiddle, a solução #2 tem o tempo de execução menor

Answer (score 1):

Consegui o resultado esperando utilizando a seguinte sintaxe:

```
 Select 
     r.*,
     s.via 
 from recibos r 
 inner join generate_series(1,2) s(via) on 1=1
 where codigo = 1;
```

Se alguém tiver outra sugestão de como obter o mesmo resultado, agradeço.

Comment: O uso de um `CROSS JOIN`  dispensa o uso de `ON`.